WPF - DataGrid - HeaderTemplate not working - column header is blank
I need to add a custom image in a WPF column header

I tried changing width/height/Background of the StackPanel
I tried changing the content and other properties of the TextBlock

It just does not work, I get a blank column header with nothing in it
What am I missing ?
<DataGrid Sorting="OnDataSort_Files" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True">
     <DataGrid.Columns>

         <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" SortMemberPath="Name">

             <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{DynamicResource FilesTabIcon}" Width="19" Height="19"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>      
                    
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding FileTypeImageSource}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" MouseLeftButtonUp="OnClick_FilesItem" MouseRightButtonUp="OnClick_FilesItem" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        ...

Thanks for your help

the issue was a style leftover, removing it was my solution ...please admin delete this question

this works on my end so it should also work for you, just replace my path with your image:
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourProperties}">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Path Data="M20 14H14V20H10V14H4V10H10V4H14V10H20V14Z" Fill="HotPink"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                    
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>


the issue was a style leftover, removing it was my solution ...please admin delete this question
